# Is there a better calculation for accuracy in vanilla neural network with confusion matrix?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, confusion-matrix

My prof say that the code in function hitung_akurasi is wrong to calculated accuracy with confusion matrix but he didn't tell a hint. From my code give final accuracy in each epoch, when i run try in
leaning rate = 0.1, hidden layer = 1, epoch = 100 for 39219 features. the data i used are all numerical.

```
y_temp= []
y_temp2 = []

for i in range(len(y_train)):
  temp = ([y_train.iloc[i]])
  y_temp.append(temp)
y = np.array((y_temp), dtype=np.float64)

for i in range(len(y_test)):
  temp2= ([y_test.iloc[i]])
  y_temp2.append(temp2)
y2 = np.array((y_temp2), dtype=np.float64)

# Activation function
def sigmoid(t):
  t = t.astype(np.float64)
  return 1/(1+np.exp(-t))

def sigmoid_derivative(t):
  t = t.astype(np.float64)
  return sigmoid(t) * (1-sigmoid(t))

def tanh(t):
  t = t.astype(np.float64)
  return np.tanh(t)

def tanh_derivative(t):
  t = t.astype(np.float64)
  return 1-np.tanh(t)**2

def relu(t):
  t = t.astype(np.float64)
  return np.maximum(0, t)

def relu_derivative(t):
  t = t.astype(np.float64)
  t[t <= 0] = 0
  t[t > 0] = 1
  return t

class NeuralNetworks:
    def __init__(self, perceptron, x, y, hidden_layer, lr, bias):
        np.random.seed(42)
        self.hl = hidden_layer
        self.weights = {}
        self.input = x
        self.perceptron_input = self.input.shape[1]
        self.perceptron_output = 1
        self.lr = lr
        self.y = y
        
        # inisialisasi weight untuk setiap neuron 
        # looping with total layers
        for i in range(hidden_layer): 
            # inisialisasis weight pada layer awal sampai sebelum terakhir (layer ke-i) || initialization layer
            self.weights[i] = np.random.rand(self.perceptron_input,perceptron) * sqrt(2.0 / self.perceptron_input)  
        # inisialisasis weight pada layer terakhir (layer output) || initialization weight in output layer
        self.weights[hidden_layer] = np.random.randn(perceptron, self.perceptron_output) * np.sqrt(1. / perceptron) 
    
        self.y = y
        self.output = np.zeros(y.shape)
    
    #forward propagation
    def forward_prop(self, hidden_layer):
        self.layer = {}
        
        #perhitungan activation function ReLu
        self.layer[0] = relu(np.dot(self.input, self.weights[0])) 
        
        for i in range(hidden_layer+1): # tambah 1 karena agar looping semua lapisan
            if i != 0: 
                #perhitungan activation function ReLu
                self.layer[i] = relu(np.dot(self.layer[i-1], self.weights[i]))
            
            if i == hidden_layer:
                #perhitungan activation function sigmoid di layer akhir
                self.layer[i] = sigmoid(np.dot(self.layer[i-1], self.weights[i]))
                
        return self.layer[i]
    
    def backward_prop(self, hidden_layer):
        dW = {}
        E = {}
        
        #backpropagation output layer
        E[hidden_layer] = (self.y - self.output) * sigmoid_derivative(self.output)
        self.layer[hidden_layer-1] = np.multiply(E[hidden_layer], sigmoid_derivative(self.layer[hidden_layer]))
        dW[hidden_layer] = np.dot(self.layer[hidden_layer-1].T, E[hidden_layer]) #turunan dari weight
        
        # looping backward to hidden layer previously
        for i in reversed(range(hidden_layer)): 
            if i != 0:
                E[i] = np.dot(E[i+1], self.weights[i+1].T) * relu_derivative(self.layer[i])
                self.layer[i] = np.multiply(E[i], relu_derivative(self.layer[i]))
                dW[i] = np.dot(self.layer[i-1].T,E[i])
            if i == 0:
                E[0]= np.dot(E[1], self.weights[1].T) * relu_derivative(self.layer[0])
                self.layer[i] = np.multiply(E[i], relu_derivative(self.layer[i]))
                dW[0] = np.dot(self.input.T, E[0])
        for i in range(hidden_layer+1):
            self.weights[i] += self.lr * dW[i]  #lr
            
    def train(self, epoch):
        accuracies = []
        cross_entropies = []
        recalls = []
        
        for i in range(epoch):
            print("Epoch: ", i + 1, end=" ------ ")
            self.output = self.forward_prop(self.hl) 
            self.backward_prop(self.hl)
            akurasi, recall = self.hitung_akurasi(self.input, self.y)
            cross_entropy = self.cross_entropy_loss(self.output, self.y)
            accuracies.append(akurasi)
            recalls.append(recall)
            cross_entropies.append(cross_entropy)
        return accuracies, cross_entropies, recalls
    
    # accuracy calculation  
    def hitung_akurasi(self, X, y):
        predictions = []
        counter = 0
        
        for i in range(len(y)): #loop
            if self.output[i] >= 0.5: #if output greaterthan 0.5
                prediksi = 1 
            else:
                prediksi = 0
            predictions.append(prediksi)
            

            if predictions[i] == y[i]:
                counter = counter+1
            
        akurasi = (counter/len(y)) * 100
        
        cm = confusion_matrix(predictions, y)
        true_positive = cm[1,1]
        true_negative = cm[0,0]
        false_positive = cm[0,1]
        false_negative = cm[1,0]
    #     confussion_matrix['TP'] / (confussion_matrix['TP'] + confussion_matrix['TN'])
        recall = true_positive / (true_positive + true_negative)


        print('Accuracy: '+ str(akurasi))
        return akurasi, recall
    

    def cross_entropy_loss(self, predictions, targets):
        """
        Menghitung Cross-entropy loss antara prediksi dan target.
        :param predictions: array numpy 2D, probabilitas prediksi dari model
        :param targets: array numpy 2D, distribusi probabilitas label yang sebenarnya
        :return: float, nilai Cross-entropy loss
        """
        # Mencegah nilai log(0) dengan menambahkan epsilon ke nilai prediksi
        epsilon = 1e-12
        predictions = np.clip(predictions, epsilon, 1. - epsilon)

        # Menghitung Cross-entropy loss
        ce_loss = -np.sum(targets * np.log(predictions)) / len(predictions)
    
        return ce_loss

    
    def testing(self, X, y):
        self.input = X
        confussion_matrix ={'TP': 0, 'FP': 0, 'TN': 0, 'FN': 0}
        output = self.forward_prop(self.hl)
        
        for y_hat, y_test in zip(output, y):
            if y_test == 0 and y_hat == 0:
                confussion_matrix['FN']+=1
            elif y_test == 0 and y_hat == 1:
                confussion_matrix['FP']+=1
            elif y_test == 1 and y_hat == 1:
                confussion_matrix['TP']+=1
            else:
                confussion_matrix['TN']+=1
        return confussion_matrix
```

This is the printout until epoch: 33 then I stop the kernel.
[image]

Comment: Accuracy is percentage that your algorithm "got right". You got true positives and true negatives right (you get these from the confusion matrix).